# How to find the size of a filesystem?

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, lvm, btrfs

How can I find out the size of a filesystem in Linux? By that I mean the exact number of bytes that are used from the partition, not just the output of `df`, as that can differ from the true size when compression or deduplication is used on the filesystem.

The size of the partition itself can be printed with:

```
$ lsblk -b
```

or

```
$ blockdev --getsize64 /dev/sda
```

I am looking for something similar for the filesystem.

PS: This is for LVM grow/shrink stuff. I am mostly interested in ext2/3/4 and btrfs, but any other filesystem info is appreciated as well.

Comment: I think you mean "partition" or "HD" with "filesystem".

Comment: No, I mean "filesystem". A filesystem size can be different from the partition it is on, this is common when you grow or shrink partitions.

Answer (score 15):

If you want filesystem information and not partition/volume information, I think you'll have to use filesystem-specific tools.

In the case of the extN systems, that would be `dumpe2fs`. And `dumpe2fs` doesn't directly print the size in bytes, as far as I can tell. It does, however, print the block count and the size of blocks, so you can parse the output instead:

```
$ dumpe2fs -h /dev/sda1 |& awk -F: '/Block count/{count=$2} /Block size/{size=$2} END{print count*size}'           
29999980544
```

In my case, this size is slightly different from the partition size:

```
$ parted /dev/sda u b p
Model: ATA ST500LT012-1DG14 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500107862016B
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start          End            Size           File system     Name  Flags
 1      17408B         30000000511B   29999983104B   ext4                  boot, esp
 2      30000807936B   453049843711B  423049035776B  ext4
 5      453049843712B  495999516671B  42949672960B   ext4
 3      495999516672B  500102862847B  4103346176B    linux-swap(v1)
 4      500102862848B  500107845119B  4982272B                             bios_grub
```

The partition size is 29999983104 bytes, 2560 bytes more than a multiple of the block size, which is why the size reported by `dumpe2fs` is less.

Comment: What about other file systems than extNfs, like iso9660?

Answer (score 8):

It depends on the filesystem you want to investigate:

## ext2, ext3, ext4 file system

```
dumpe2fs -h /dev/sda1 | grep '^Block'
```

You have to multiply block count and block size to get number of bytes.

## ISO-9660 file system

```
isoinfo -d -i ubuntu-18.10-desktop-amd64.iso | grep -A1 '^Logical block size'
```

The unit for volume size is logical blocks, so you have to multiply volume size and logical block size to get number of bytes.

## BTRFS file system

As one btrfs can include several devices, the command takes the mountpoint as argument

```
btrfs filesystem usage -b /mnt/mountpoint | grep 'Device size'
```

Answer (score 3):

For btrfs, you can use:

```
sudo btrfs filesystem usage -b /mountpoint
```