# How to to print the size of a filesystem in bytes?

Tags: command-line, filesystem

**Question:**

I would like to print the size of a filesystem in bytes. I have read [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/622523/653546), but when running the suggested command, it prints the output in scientific notation:

```
manuel@manuel-ThinkPad-T460:~$ sudo dumpe2fs -h /dev/sdb2 |& awk -F: '/Block count/{count=$2} /Block size/{size=$2} END{print count*size}'
9.96147e+11
```

**My attempt to solve**

I tried to manually adapt the command and came up with this command, but it provides a false result:

```
manuel@manuel-ThinkPad-T460:~$ sudo dumpe2fs -h /dev/sdb2 |& awk -F: '/Block count/{count=$2} /Block size/{size=$2} END{printf "%d\n", count*size}'
2147483647
```

**Side info**

The values of the field `Block size` is `4096` and of `Block count` it is `243200000`. The product is `996147200000`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default implementation of `awk` in recent versions of Ubuntu is `mawk`, whose default numeric output format appears to `%.6g`. You can alter that by setting built-in variable `OFMT` to something longer

Ex.

```
$ printf 'Block count: 243200000\nBlock size: 4096\n' | 
    mawk -F: '/Block count/{count=$2} /Block size/{size=$2} END{print count*size}'
9.96147e+11
```

but

```
$ printf 'Block count: 243200000\nBlock size: 4096\n' | 
    mawk -F: '/Block count/{count=$2} /Block size/{size=$2} END{print count*size}' OFMT='%.12g'
996147200000
```

or (using your `printf` approach)

```
$ printf 'Block count: 243200000\nBlock size: 4096\n' | 
    mawk -F: '/Block count/{count=$2} /Block size/{size=$2} END{printf "%.12g\n", count*size}'
996147200000
```

(`printf "%d\n"` doesn't work because the values are converted internally to floating point, I think).

---

From `man mawk`

```
OFMT      format for printing numbers; initially = "%.6g"
```

Answer (score 2):

While not necessary being equal to the size of the *file system*, the size of the *partition the file system is stored on* can be printed by utilizing `lsblk`. On most (but not all) systems the partition and the file system overlap exactly, providing an equal result. However, this cannot be guaranteed.

Here's the info from my /dev/sda1 partition:

```
sudo dumpe2fs -h /dev/sda1
dumpe2fs 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
Filesystem volume name:   <none>
Last mounted on:          /media/user/be816c0e-e757-4b20-8bef-5ce79854eb77
Filesystem UUID:          be816c0e-e757-4b20-8bef-5ce79854eb77
Filesystem magic number:  0xEF53
Filesystem revision #:    1 (dynamic)
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype extent flex_bg sparse_super large_file huge_file uninit_bg dir_nlink extra_isize
Filesystem flags:         signed_directory_hash 
Default mount options:    user_xattr acl
Filesystem state:         clean
Errors behavior:          Continue
Filesystem OS type:       Linux
Inode count:              819200
Block count:              3251200
Reserved block count:     162559
Free blocks:              1040435
Free inodes:              328525
First block:              0
Block size:               4096
Fragment size:            4096
Reserved GDT blocks:      1023
Blocks per group:         32768
Fragments per group:      32768
Inodes per group:         8192
Inode blocks per group:   512
RAID stride:              32717
Flex block group size:    16
Filesystem created:       Mon Mar 31 11:36:45 2014
Last mount time:          Mon Jan 30 15:26:07 2017
Last write time:          Mon Jan 30 15:26:07 2017
Mount count:              175
Maximum mount count:      -1
Last checked:             Wed Sep  9 17:58:29 2015
Check interval:           0 (<none>)
Lifetime writes:          34 GB
Reserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)
Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)
First inode:              11
Inode size:           256
Required extra isize:     28
Desired extra isize:      28
Journal inode:            8
Default directory hash:   half_md4
Directory Hash Seed:      8a419c50-75fe-41af-8492-96a2cc20cdb5
Journal backup:           inode blocks
Journal features:         journal_incompat_revoke
Journal size:             128M
Journal length:           32768
Journal sequence:         0x00015415
Journal start:            0
```

Comparison:

```
echo -e 'Block count:3251200\nBlock size: 4096\n' |      mawk -F: '/Block count/{count=$2} /Block size/{size=$2} END{print count*size}' OFMT='%.12g'
```

**13316915200**

```
$ lsblk --noheadings -b /dev/sda1 -o size
```

**13316915200**

As you can see, fewer keystrokes provide **exactly the same result** without pipes.

Source `man lsblk`

Comment: I'm under the impression this displays the size of the partition according to the partition table, not of the file system stored on it.

Comment: @Multisync I see no difference in output. I have no doubt future readers will appreciate all the options they can get. :-)

Comment: Your post stated that your command prints the file system size, which is not true. (No pun intended.) In order not to confuse the reader, I have edited your post and provided some details regarding partition vs. file system size.